# Can't implement Twilio OTP verification (Application was not found)

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-api, one-time-password

First of all, Here's what I have done,

1. I started with [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/twilio-verification-sdk-integration-guide) guide, and deployed my sample backend using one click on heroku server(as mentioned in docs). then I added gradel dependencies and rest of the code as mentioned in docs.

here's my initTokenService

```
private void initTokenServerApi() {
    String TOKEN_SERVER_URL = "https://pixelolio.herokuapp.com/";
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(TOKEN_SERVER_URL)
            .build();
    tokenServerApi = retrofit.create(Api.class);
}
```

here's my tokenServerApi Callback

```
tokenServerApi
                    .getToken(numberToVerify)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<TokenServerResponse>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<TokenServerResponse> call,
                                               Response<TokenServerResponse> response) {
                            Log.e("response", String.valueOf(response.body().getJwtToken()));
                            String jwtToken = response.body().getJwtToken();
                            twilioVerification.startVerification(jwtToken, Via.SMS);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<TokenServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {


                        }
                    });
```

here's MyVerificationReceiver

```
public class MyVerificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        VerificationStatus verificationStatus = TwilioVerification.getVerificationStatus(intent);
        Log.e("verified", String.valueOf(verificationStatus.getVerificationException()));
        Log.e("verified", String.valueOf(verificationStatus.getState()));
    }
}
```

here's my TokenServerApi

```
  public interface TokenServerApi {

    @POST("/verify/token")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<TokenServerResponse> getToken(@Field("phone_number") String phoneNumber);

}
```

if I run my app at this stage than I can generate JWT successfully. But I am getting getting "Application was not valid" when I log  "verificationStatus.getVerificationException();"

2. I implemented 2nd step. **Now here is my question , do I need to create my backend from scratch or I can use [this](https://github.com/authy/authy-sdk-backend/). as it also has an option to deploy on heroku?**
3. I have registered my application successfully in Twilio Verification API.

I run my app after completing 3rd step but still getting same error.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/verify/twilio-verification-sdk-android-sdk-reference

Comment: im not getting any otp messag even after calling startVerification. @BhavikMakwana just the error is coming in Logs.